# Know if aPython list has one item or more than one item

Tags: python-2.7

Say I have two possibilities, of which I know neither in advance.
A=["abc","def","ghi"] or A="abc".

I want to do something if length of list is more than one.
I can't simply do "if len(A)>1 do this" because both the conditions will satisfy this requirement.

I somehow want to be able to distinguish between the two possibilities. How do do that in Python ?

Thank you

Below is the edited\added part ..

As you see the first line of output ..instead of showing [[None,dinner]] 
is showing [[None, 'd'], [None, 'i'], [None, 'n'], [None, 'n'], [None, 'e'], [None, 'r']]
.

How to solve this? Where am I going wrong?
Really sorry for a confusing post and editing post a couple of comments are already there ...

The code below

```
menu = {'dinner':
        {'chicken':'good',
         'beef':'average',
         'vegetarian':{
               'tofu':'good',
               'salad':{
                        'caeser':'bad',
                        'italian':'average'}
               },
         'pork':'bad'}
    }
vertices, edges = [],[]
counter = 1
def TranverseTheTree(DictTree, parent=None):
    for edge, vertex in DictTree.iteritems():
        if isinstance(vertex, dict):
            global counter
            counter += 1
            vertices.append(vertex.keys())
            edges.append([[parent,i] if len(edge)>1 else [parent,edge] for i in edge])
            TranverseTheTree(vertex, edge)
        else:
            vertices.append(vertex)
            edges.append([vertex, edge])

TranverseTheTree(menu)
for each in edges:
    print each
```

The output below

```
[[None, 'd'], [None, 'i'], [None, 'n'], [None, 'n'], [None, 'e'], [None, 'r']]
['bad', 'pork']
['good', 'chicken']
[['dinner', 'v'], ['dinner', 'e'], ['dinner', 'g'], ['dinner', 'e'], ['dinner', 't'], ['dinner', 'a'], ['dinner', 'r'], ['dinner', 'i'], ['dinner', 'a'], ['dinner', 'n']]
['good', 'tofu']
[['vegetarian', 's'], ['vegetarian', 'a'], ['vegetarian', 'l'], ['vegetarian', 'a'], ['vegetarian', 'd']]
['average', 'italian']
['bad', 'caeser']
['average', 'beef']
```

Process finished with exit code 0

Comment: You could test `type(A) == list`, though that will exclude tuples and other iterables. Perhaps you could have your condition be `len(A) > 1 and type(A) != str`. Strings are tricky because they *are* iterable, and each element is a one-character string, which can confound attempts to duck-type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first case, `A` is a `list`, in the second one, it is a `string`. So you can distinguish between them by

```
if type(A) == list:
    # do something
elif type(A) == str:
    # do something else
else:
    # don't do anything
```

Comment: My apologies ... I should have included the context as well .. so editing the question ..